# Stencil web components are not rendering for angular application (Angular 17)

Tags: angular, web-component, stenciljs, stencil-component

I am using Nx to create a mono repo where I have a core stencil library which cross compiles the angular components into react and angular.

I was able to build and render the component on react app. However, when I try to launch Angular, I see no errors on console and the app build. I can even see the component on the body section of the rendered html. But the component content doesn't render.

Here is the repo link. https://github.com/pyVarad/nucleus

```
Process to run
Step 1: Clone the repo.
Step 2: npm install
Step 3: npm run build
Step 4: cd packages/nucleus-angular-consumer
Step 5: ng serve
```

Any direction will be of great help.